# Is a bug in specific scenario in a single thread application will be shown in every execute?

Tags: multithreading, debugging

If we see a bug in a single thread application can we assume that it will emerge again every time we run the application?

> EDIT: Assume we don't have any random function or number in the code.

Comment: No. In simple cases, uninitialised variables, for instance, may start at a random value that "works" sometimes, fails other. And talking of random, `42 / rand()` will generate an exception only when `rand()` returns 0. There's of course 101 other reasons, especially when you get into user input issues.

Comment: Yes, You are right about random numbers, but for input, imagine we have single inputs stream for every time we execute the app.